# Как спарсить определенные элементы из XML-файла?

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть xml-файл с данной структурой:

```
<ValCurs>
<Valute ID="R01010">
<NumCode>036</NumCode>
<CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
<Value>44,1039</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="R01020A">
<NumCode>944</NumCode>
<CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name>
<Value>33,5431</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="R01035">
<NumCode>826</NumCode>
<CharCode>GBP</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства</Name>
<Value>80,6068</Value>
</Valute>
...
</ValCurs>
```

Нужно спарсить определенные валюты по ID у тега Valute c помощью XMLPullParser'а. К сожалению, при конкретизации аттрибутов всё ломается и не выводится.

```
private void pullDataInArticles(XmlPullParser xmlPullParser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Valuet")) {
            if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Value") && xmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(0).equals("R01235")) {
                String title = xmlPullParser.getText();
                currentArticle.setTitle_usd(title);
                Log.d("valueXML",title);
            } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Value") && xmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(0).equals("R01239")){
                String title = xmlPullParser.getText();
                currentArticle.setTitle_euro(title);
                Log.d("valueXML",title);
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Valuet")) {
            articles.add(currentArticle);
            currentArticle = new Article();
        }
        eventType = xmlPullParser.next();
    }
    triggerObserver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала, исправьте опечатки: в xml `Valute`, в коде `Valuet`.

Comment: А почему бы не воспользоваться XPath: /ValCurs/Valute[@ID='R01010']/Name